# Amd 16.04 low graphics mode

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics

I have been trying for the past few days to install 'amdgpu-pro' on my PC but I keep getting missing firmware warnings and when I reboot my PC is running in low graphics mode.

I have a Radeon rx480. I have already tried looking on many different websites for a solution but many don't work or I don't understand.

I have done the normal cd then the folder, the I did

```
./amdgpu-pro-install -y.
```

I got this missing firmware error:

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
```

Then when I reboot I get told I'm running in low graphics mode

kernel 4.8.0-36-generic

I have just uninstalled the driver so i can reboot my pc for tomorrow but I cannot find a solution.
Thanks
I am a student so i might be at school so i cant reply

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us exactly what you've tried and exactly what error you receive.

Comment: Please provide commands you have run and errors witnessed.

Comment: Which kernel version are you using? Run `uname -r` to see. I think you might need the newer kernel and xorg from the HWE stack to get RX 480 working properly.

Comment: I think it is 4.8 because when it was building the amdgpu-pro it said 4.8._ generic but i cannot check right now. It is the one straight from the Ubuntu website

Comment: this is the kernel 4.8.0-36-generic

Comment: please help me please

Comment: bump 2short////

Answer (score 0):

I solved my amdgpu-pro-17.30-465504 installation problem by following Mark Maurer's advise [Troubles installing AMD drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963962/troubles-installing-amd-drivers/964007#964007) and ensure that I had "HWE - hardware enablement" installed. So I followed the instructions on this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack and then reinstalled the amdgpu-pro drivers successfully.